# Lebesgue integral of a continuous function is not defined on the infinite interval.

Tags: real-analysis

We know that the Lebesgue integral of a continuous function on a bounded interval is equal to the counterpart Riemann integral. However is there any example of a continuous function $f: [0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}\int_{[0,t]}fd\lambda$ exists but $\int_{[0,\infty)}fd\lambda$ is not defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, look for something for which the improper integral only converges conditionally, such as $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$.